# $\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{(e^x-e^{-x})x^\frac{1}{3}}$ why does it diverges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$$\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{(e^x-e^{-x})x^\frac{1}{3}}$$

Hi everyone, i thought that i proved that this integral converges but than i looked at the answers and saw it diverges.
Here is my proof:
Let there be $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{3}}$, we know that $\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{x^\frac{1}{3}}$ converge, hence lets check the limit of:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^\frac{1}{3}}{(e^x-e^{-x})x^\frac{1}{3}} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{(e^x-e^{-x})} = \infty$$

and since $\int g(x)$ is converging so than $\int(x)$ is also converging.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The limit is infinity... If it was finite then it would be ok!

Comment: The limit is infinity, you cannot conclude that you have convergence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed we can't conclude for convergence when limit is $\infty$.

To solve note that

$$\frac{1}{(e^x-e^{-x})x^\frac{1}{3}}\sim \frac{1}{2x\cdot x^\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2x^\frac{4}{3}}$$

which suggests to use limit comparison test with $\int \frac{1}{x^\frac{4}{3}}\,dx$.